# How Do I Create a Derived Collection

Tags: collection

I am trying to follow what "uguptu" is recommending here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/225234/

In particular, I am trying to run my own highly specific query on the sales/order model.  I would like to derive my own collection from the sales/order_collection but need to know where to put that code he recommends.  Do I put it in the model?  If so, how do I modify config.xml for a tableless model?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether I understand this question.

> To make it correct, you derive a custom collection from the standard
>   one. You either override _initSelect() and put your filter
>   modifications and joins there, or you put it into some public method
>   that can be executed for the collection in case you need a custom
>   filtering.

So just put it in `_initSelect()`

Like this:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Order_Collection extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
{
    public function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->getSelect()->join( array('table_alias'=>$this->getTable('module/table_name')), 'main_table.foreign_id = table_alias.primary_key', array('table_alias.*'), 'schema_name_if_different');
        return parent::_initSelect();
    }
}
```

But I highly recommend to use `joinTable()`, `joinField`, `joinAttribute` instead of directly working on the `Zend_Db` instance.

## model and resource model in config.xml

Normally you define a prefix to use the models with `Mage::getModel()` and `Mage::getSingleton()`. If models write to the database, they have a resource model and a collection class. this is defined via the `<resourceModel>` node.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <namespace_module> <!-- prefix -->
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>

<!-- What happens with Mage::getModel('...')->getResourceModel() -->
<!-- What happens with Mage::getModel('...')->getCollection() -->
                <resourceModel>namespace_module_resource</resourceModel>

            </namespace_module>
            <namespace_module_resource>
                <class>Idee_ShowCart_Model_Resource</class>
            </namespace_module_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: But what file do you put that model resource class in?

Comment: The above wasn't what I didn't know.  What I need to know is, having done the above, what changes do I need to make to config.xml for my module to know about the above class and for that matter, where do I put that class?  Somewhere in Models/Resources/...?

Comment: And the reason I wanted to make a custom collection is, I'm doing reporting on existing tables/models.  My module doesn't really have any of it's own.  I'm not adding another table, then doing CRUD stuff.  I'm digging out data from existing tables/models.

Comment: You can place that code in Namespace/Module/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php

Comment: edited the post, I hope this is enough to be understand.